# jquery image slider with numbers for asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need jquery image slider with number like the one used here:

http://jtsplatmaster.com/

at the top.

I see there are many jquery sliders available but I need one with numbers. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can use any slider that you will write the titles. I mean if you use slider and you can put extra div and put label there and change it's text.

Or check this.
http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is very customizable and can do this

Example with a pager: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager-over.html